# could not find react-redux context value error triggering randomly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, exception, redux, react-redux

Here is my code for displaying the contents of my Redux store state in JSON:

```
   function ShowCartContents() {
      // Convert object to JSON before rendering
      const cartContentsJSON = JSON.stringify(useStore().getState())
    
      return (
        <div>
            <h2>Cart contents: {cartContentsJSON}</h2>
          </div>
      );
    }
// Works fine
```

Everything is working just fine but when I try to add button with onClick attribute to call another function I'm getting error:

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

The weird thing here is that I do have `<App>` wrapped in `<Provider>` but this error occurs and I can't find any logic why this happens. Here is the beginning of my `App.js`:

```
    import './App.css';
    import MenuItems from './components/Navbar/MenuItems';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { createStore } from 'redux';
    import {AddItemToCart, DeleteItemFromCart, Counter} from './cart.js';
    import Header from './header';
    import Footer from './footer.js';
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import { useSelector, useStore } from 'react-redux';
    
    let store = createStore(Counter);
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
      rootElement
    );
const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState([])
```

Here is how I tried to add my button with OnClick for function call:

```
    function ShowCartContents() {
      const cartContentsJSON = JSON.stringify(useStore().getState())
    
      return (
        <div>
            <h2>Cart contents: {cartContentsJSON}</h2>
            <button onClick={(e)=> {ShowCustomerInfo(e)}}>Proceed</button>
// Also tried: <button onClick={<ShowCustomerInfo/>}>Proceed</button>
          </div>
      );
    }
```

This triggers the error above. Here is my `ShowCustomerInfo` function:

```
function ShowCustomerInfo(){
  fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/getCustomerInfo`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
          setCustomerInfo(response.result);
          console.log(response.result);
      });
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>
            {customerInfo}
          </h2>
        </div>
      );
}
```

What is causing the exception? Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: While it's not strictly related to your issue: you **should not call `useStore` or `store.getState()` in your own code**.  Instead, you should be [calling the `useSelector` hook from React-Redux and passing in a "selector" function](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#reading-state-from-the-store-with-useselector).

Comment: @markerikson I know, but actually, this exception is the reason I avoid using hooks if possible.

Comment: What "exception" are you referring to? FWIW, looking at the code examples you're showing here, it seems like you've got some significant misunderstandings of how to correctly use React-Redux. I'd strongly recommend reading through the tutorial I linked.

Comment: The problem is your button onClick.  You are trying to call  a component as an event handler.  You can’t do this.  You need to use the onClick to set a state and use that state to render a component conditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot render a component from an event handler such as `onClick`.  An event handler can update state and perform side effects like API calls but it cannot `return` anything.  If you call components as a function instead of rendering them properly then you will get errors like "Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a `<Provider>`".

Instead you want to update the state from your `onClick` handler and conditionally render different components based on the state.  You could use some sort of value like a `boolean` state `showCustomerInfo` or a `number` state `page`.  Since we are loading data into the `array` `customerInfo`, we can check to see if the length is greater than `0` and only show the customer info once it's not empty.

```
export const App = () => {
  const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState([]);

  // use this state so that we can disable hide the "Proceed"
  // button immediately, before the fetch has completed
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  const cartContentsJSON = JSON.stringify(state);

  function loadCustomerInfo() {
    console.log("clicked");
    // can use async/await, but fetch is fine too
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/getCustomerInfo`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        // could store this in redux instead
        setCustomerInfo(response.result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Cart contents: {cartContentsJSON}</h2>
      <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={() => loadCustomerInfo()}>
        Proceed
      </button>
      {customerInfo.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h3>Customer Info</h3>
          <p>{JSON.stringify(customerInfo)}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You know everything about React/Redux/Javascript/Typescript. Can I ask where (or how) you have learned all this?

Comment: I'm mostly self-taught.  Just keep on playing and learning!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few anti-patterns I see in your code like:

1. Your `App.js` creates a state which is outside of your
   entire component tree as you do

   `const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState([])`

   after creating the `rootElement` and using it in
   `ReactDOM.render`. You must carry this state into an actual
   component as any state must be part of React
   dataflow but what you do actually violates this.

   After refactoring that part you can use this state
   in your `ShowCustomerInfo`
   but you should call it as `<ShowCustomerInfo/>` instead of `ShowCustomerInfo()` as it renders `JSX` and again you should do this, because you want to make this component part of React dataflow otherwise you are just treating it just like a regular function.
2. This is just a naming convention but your `App.js` file doesn't
   define `<App/>` component but just renders it. I would expect
   your `App.js` to be `index.js` as it's going to be the
   beginning of your virtual-dom with `ReactDOM.render`.

If you make changes considering first part, you'll get rid of the problem I believe.

Comment: That customerInfo is declared inside App() function. I changed my onClick call to <ShowCustomerInfo/> but the same exception occurs.